# Magento empty a category (1.5)

Tags: magento, categories

I'm wondering if there is a quick way to remove all products from a particular category? 
Or am I stuck with getting all the categories products then looping through and removing the category from each one?

I'm planning on running this on a cron.

Edit: Currently I'm using setCategoryIds() but it seems a very inefficient way of doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is indeed to loop through each product;

set an array of category ids, $ids
then use the  setCategoryIds($ids) method in the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product to set the category id for the product.

Let me know if you want the actual code for this or if you are looking for a different way.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm actually using setCategoryIds(), It seems a really laborious way of emptying a category though and I was hoping there was a quicker method I could use. (I maybe should have mentioned that. I will edit the question.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about cron, but you could use the import/export functionnality. <s>Or, depending on how much products are in those categories, you could use the bulk procesing function in the admin's products grid. I have a module to filter this grid by categories: if you want it just let me know and I'll upload it somewhere.</s> oops, the category is not available by bulk attributes updating. but the import/export will do just fine.

Comment: Thanks but this does need to be run via a cron job

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested, but something like this should do it:

```
$category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($id);
$products = $category->getProductCollection();
foreach($products as $product) {
    $productCategories = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $index = array_search($productCategories, $id);
    unset($productCategories[$index]);
    $product->setCategoryIds($productCategories);
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this (Slight typo though: $category->getCategoryIds(); should be $product->getCategoryIds();)